# Stored procedure performance Select SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[_tbHRPro](
    [ideID] [int] IDENTITY(-2147483648,1) NOT NULL,
    [FID] [int] NULL,
    [myDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [myTime] [time](7) NULL,
    [oValue] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [pValue] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__tbHRPro] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ideIDID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Then, I have the following stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @MonthID int = 2;
DECLARE @Year varchar(5) = '2014';
DECLARE @date1 DATE;
DECLARE @date2 DATE;

SET @date1 = DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,1,CAST(CAST(@MonthID AS VARCHAR)+'/01/'+CAST(@Year AS VARCHAR)AS DATE)))
SET @date2 = CAST('01/01/'+CAST(@Year AS VARCHAR)AS DATE)

SELECT 
            a.ideID
            , a.FID
            , b.FC
            , a.myDate
            , a.myTime
            , a.oValue
            , a.pValue 
        INTO 
            #TEMPX
        FROM 
            _tbHRPro a 
            INNER JOIN _FC b ON a.FID = b.FID
        WHERE 
            myDate BETWEEN Dateadd(day, -1, @date2) AND dateadd(day, 1, @date1)

        ;WITH CTE AS
            (
                SELECT 
                    T1.ideID
                    , T1.FID
                    , T1.FC
                    , T1.myDate
                    , T1.myTime
                    , T1.oValue
                    , CASE WHEN T1.oValue = 0 THEN 0 ELSE T1.oValue - T2.oValue END xValue
                    , T1.pValue
                    , CAST(T1.myDate AS datetime) + CAST(T1.myTime as datetime) oDateTime
                    , (CASE WHEN T1.oValue = 0 THEN 0 ELSE T1.oValue - T2.oValue END) - T1.pValue sDel
                FROM 
                    #TEMPX T1
                    LEFT JOIN #TEMPX T2 on T1.FID = T2.FID 
                    AND DATEADD(HOUR, -1, CAST(T1.myDate AS datetime) + CAST(T1.myTime AS datetime)) = CAST(T2.myDate AS datetime) + CAST(T2.myTime AS datetime)
                    LEFT JOIN #TEMPX T3 on T1.FID = T3.FID 
                    AND DATEADD(HOUR, 1, CAST(T1.myDate AS datetime) + CAST(T1.myTime AS datetime)) = CAST(T3.myDate AS datetime) + CAST(T3.myTime AS datetime)
            )
        , CTE2 AS
            (      
                SELECT 
                    T1.ideID
                    , T1.FID
                    , T1.FC
                    , T1.myDate
                    , T1.myTime
                    , T1.oValue
                    , CASE WHEN T1.oValue = 0 then (T2.xValue + T3.xValue) / 2 ELSE T1.xValue END AS xValue 
                    , T1.pValue  
                    , (CASE WHEN T1.oValue = 0 then (T2.xValue + T3.xValue) / 2 ELSE T1.xValue END) - T1.pValue sDel     
                FROM 
                    CTE T1
                    LEFT JOIN CTE T2 ON T1.myDate = T2.myDate 
                    AND T1.FID = T2.FID 
                    AND DATEADD(HOUR, -1, T1.oDateTime)= T2.oDateTime
                    LEFT JOIN CTE T3 on T1.myDate = T3.myDate and T1.FID = T3.FID 
                    AND DATEADD(HOUR, 1, T1.oDateTime)= T3.oDateTime
            )

        SELECT 
            ideID
            , FID
            , FC
            , myDate
            , myTime
            , oValue
            , xValue
            , pValue
            , sDel
        INTO 
            #_vwHRPro
        FROM 
            CTE2
        ORDER BY 
            FC
            , myDate
            , myTime

        ;WITH ff AS 
            (
                SELECT 
                    FID
                    , FC
                    , DATEADD(hh, - 1, DATEADD(hh, DATEPART(hh, myTime), myDate)) AS newDate
                    , xValue
                FROM 
                    #_vwHRPro
            )

        SELECT 
            A.FID1
            , A.FC1
            , A.myDate1
            , A.totxValue1
            , B.FID2
            , B.FC2
            , B.myDate2
            , B.totxValue2
            , C.FID3
            , C.FC3
            , C.myDate3
            , C.totxValue3
        INTO 
            #_vwpm102
        FROM 
            (
                SELECT 
                    FID AS FID1
                    , FC AS FC1
                    , CAST(newDate AS DATE) AS myDate1
                    , SUM(xValue) AS totxValue1
                FROM 
                    ff
                WHERE 
                    (FC LIKE '%1%')
                GROUP BY 
                    FID
                    , FC
                    , CAST(newDate AS DATE)
            ) AS A FULL OUTER JOIN
            (
                SELECT 
                    FID AS FID2
                    , FC AS FC2
                    , CAST(newDate AS DATE) AS myDate2
                    , SUM(xValue) AS totxValue2
                FROM 
                    ff
                WHERE 
                    (FC LIKE '%2%')
                GROUP BY 
                    FID
                    , FC
                    , CAST(newDate AS DATE)
            ) AS B ON A.myDate1 = B.myDate2 
            FULL OUTER JOIN
            (
                SELECT 
                    FID AS FID3
                    , FC AS FC3
                    , CAST(newDate AS DATE) AS myDate3
                    , SUM(xValue) AS totxValue3
                FROM 
                    ff
                WHERE 
                    (FC LIKE '%3%')
                GROUP BY 
                    FID
                    , FC
                    , CAST(newDate AS DATE)
            ) AS C ON A.myDate1 = C.myDate3 


SELECT * FROM #_vwpm102 order by FC1, myDate1
```

I use temporary table to reduce the load time of data. The data is huge, it has been run since 2001.

The load time when I execute the stored procedure is 32sec.

I tried to run from query windows, it loads also around 30sec. But because it stored on temporary table, the 2nd time I run.

I just need to select the following statement:

```
SELECT * FROM #_vwpm102 order by FC1, myDate1
```

It loads so fast, only 1sec.

Does anyone have an idea how to minimize the load time? at least, less then 10sec.

Appreciate your help and idea. Cheers,

Comment: try to reduce your cast functions ...since your mydate and my time etc.. you cast everytime.. create a derived column if you can't chang base table.. Also, create NC index on your FC column..

Comment: @Saravanan, it reduces 5sec. It loaded 27sec now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make CTE you have "LEFT JOIN #TEMPX T3" but never use T3 - remove it. There are a lot of columns being put into the temp tables that are never used - kill them.

CAST() are expensive and you are joining on them. I would add a computed column to the _tbHRPro table.

```
ALTER TABLE _tbHRPro 
Add Column myDateTime As CAST(myDate AS datetime) + CAST(myTime as datetime)
```

(I bet you will use this for a lot of other things too.)

Then add an index on this computed column:

```
 CREATE INDEX IDX_tbHRPro_myDateTime ON _tbHRPro(myDateTime)
```

This will speed things up a lot.

Instead of having columns named FC1, FC2, FC3, myDate1, myDate2, etc. I would have a column called FCType (maybe make this a calculated column on the _FC table.)

```
ALTER TABLE _FC
Add Column FCType AS CASE WHEN FC LIKE '%1%' THEN 1
CASE WHEN FC LIKE '%2%' THEN 2
CASE WHEN FC LIKE '%3%' THEN 3 END
```

Then later you can group on this.

Then I think you can simplify the SQL to:

```
        ;WITH CTE AS
            (
                SELECT 
                    me.ideID
                    ,me.FID
                    ,me.myDateTime
                 ,CASE WHEN me.oValue = 0 or me.oValue - behind.oValue = 0 
THEN 
                 (CASE WHEN behind.oValue = 0 
                       THEN 0 
                       ELSE behind.oValue - behind2.oValue END + 
                 CASE WHEN infront.oValue = 0 
                      THEN 0 
                      ELSE me.oValue - infront.oValue END) END / 2 
                 ELSE .oValue - T2.oValue END xValue
                FROM _tbHRPro me
                LEFT JOIN _tbHRPro behind on me.FID = behind.FID 
                   AND DATEADD(HOUR, -1, me.myDateTime) = behind.myDateTime 
                LEFT JOIN _tbHRPro behind2 on me.FID = behind2.FID 
                   AND DATEADD(HOUR, -2, me.myDateTime) = behind2.myDateTime 
                LEFT JOIN _tbHRPro infront on me.FID = infront.FID 
                   AND DATEADD(HOUR, 1, me.myDateTime) = infront.myDateTime
                WHERE me.myDate 
                BETWEEN Dateadd(day, -1, @date2) AND dateadd(day, 1, @date1)
            )
```

And then make your result set from this:

```
select cast(CTE.myDateTime as Date) theDate, 
_FC.FCType, 
_FC.FC,
SUM(CTE.xValue) AS totxValue
from CTE
inner join _FC 
ON CTE.FID = _FC.FID
GROUP BY  cast(CTE.myDateTime as Date)
,_FC.FCType
,_FC.FC
```

Not really sure what the correct calculation is for xValue, but you get the idea.  And I didn't do details like take an hour off to make myDate1.

Answer (score 1):

Without table schema and execution plan people can guess only.
here in your query :
make some changes in SP

```
(1) Use recompilation sp to use statistics fullest.
(2) Don`t use function in where condition make a column in temp table and then join that column
(3) FC LIKE '%1%' and FC LIKE '%1%'  is this really necessary avoid these kind of condition.
```

Comment: I just add the table structure

Comment: (1) recompilation sp? (2) On which part? Please show me. (3)I need this condition to change from vertical to horizontal view.